# What does this poem mean? "It's not the cough that'll carry you off It's the coffin they'll carry you off in"

Tags: poetry

What does this poem mean?

> It's not the cough that'll carry you off
>   It's the coffin they'll carry you off in

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of literature

Comment: "To be carried off" is an older euphemism for "to die"—presumably originating in the longer phrase "to be carried off to heaven." The joke is in the double meaning of "carry you off" (since a fatal cough may send your soul on its way to heaven, and yet, objectively, a cough doesn't do any heavy lifting) and in the cleverness of pairing "cough"/"off" with "coffin"/"off in."

Answer (score 3):

It means it doesn't matter how you die (the cough), only that when you do, make sure you go out in style (with a nice funeral).

Answer (score 2):

It is just a [pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun),a play on words. *Cough* and *off* rhyme as do *coffin* and *off in* providing humorous effect.

As for the meaning, it means that it is not the cough that will kill you, it is the coffin in which you will be carried off. In other words, it is not so much how you die that is important but the style in which you do so.